# What's Difference between NSNotification 'object' and 'userInfo'?

Tags: ios, nsnotification

What's difference between `NSNotification`'s `object` and `userInfo`?

When I post a notification with a parameter, I can use `object` or `userInfos` to do it. But I do not know what the difference is between these two ways.

Is there some advantages to using `userInfo`? Or is using `object` enough?

Comment: If you look at the doc of `userInfos` of `NSNotification` you'll see that `object` is the notification sender, and `userInfos` contains additional info.

Comment: But `object` also can contains additional info. Is there difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `object` represent the object which posted the notification. `userInfo` contains the additional information/data for the receiving object/function.

According to [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:):

> `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`
>
> Creates a notification with a given name, sender, and information and
>   posts it to the receiver.
>
> #### Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> ```
> func postNotificationName(_ notificationName: String, object notificationSender: AnyObject?, userInfo userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
> ```
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> ```
> - (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `notificationName`
>
> The name of the notification.
>
> `notificationSender`
>
> The object posting the notification.
>
> `userInfo`
>
> Information about the the notification. May be nil.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> This method is the preferred method for posting notifications.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanna know that the "danger" if I use `object` to send additional info?

Answer (score 3):

If you define an object you can filter the notifications sent only by that object. For instance if you register for a notification, specifying an object as `notificationSender` you get notification only from that object even if the notification name is the same for other posted notifications:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver
       selector:(SEL)notificationSelector
           name:(NSString *)notificationName
         object:(id)notificationSender
```

Here is from Apple doc:

> notificationSender     The object whose notifications the observer wants
>   to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are
>   delivered to the observer.
>
> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s
>   sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

Answer (score 0):

> When working with an NSNotification object, you’ll want to familiarize yourself the userInfo dictionary, which provides access to any additional objects that may be of interest to the receiver. Understanding the object method may also be helpful if you are using the same notification on more than one object.

For Further detail go thtough this link.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsnotification-userinfo-and-object-methods.html